# django admin error on updation of data

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

When I update/delete some content through views.py file i.e via the website, everything works fine but when I try to update some data through admin panel i get this error:

IntegrityError at /admin/library/student/
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kt2`.`django_admin_log`, CONSTRAINT `django_admin_log_user_id_52fdd58701c5f563_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')

where kt2 is the name of my database.

Please help and also let me know if you need the code.

models.py

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.
class Student(AbstractUser):
    roll_number = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sem = models.IntegerField()
    pic = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    due_fine = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    USERNAME_FIELD='roll_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['username','email']
    def __str__(self):
            return self.student_name

class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.author_name


class Quantity(models.Model):
    q_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    list_of_authors=models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Quantity'
#               unique_together=(('book_name','list_of_authors'),)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.book_name

class LastFiveIssues(models.Model):
    lfi_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    one_st=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    two_st=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    three_st=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    four_st=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    five_st=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    issue_one_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    issue_two_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    issue_three_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    issue_four_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    issue_five_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    return_one_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    return_two_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    return_three_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    return_four_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    return_five_date=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural='last five issues'

class Publisher(models.Model):
    publisher_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.publisher_name

class Book(models.Model):

    last_five_issues=models.OneToOneField(LastFiveIssues)
    publisher_book=models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    authors = models.ForeignKey(Quantity)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)

    book_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=30)
    is_issued = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dep_book = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_issue = models.DateField(default = '1900-1-1')
    return_date = models.DateField(default='1900-1-1')
    book_added_on = models.DateField(default='1900-1-1')
    placed_at_shelf=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    edition_of_book = models.IntegerField()

    rare_book = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    claim_one=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    claim_two=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    claim_three=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.book_name
```

Comment: post your models.py code and your views.py code

Comment: my views.py file is way too big, and lacks comments too...it will be difficult for you to understand...ill post the models.py code. @joelgoldstick